# export 'AgChartsReact' was not found in 'ag-charts-react'

Tags: reactjs, ag-charts-react, ag-charts

I'm just trying to follow the simple examples given, like https://charts.ag-grid.com/react/create-a-basic-chart/ and it's not letting me import?

```
"ag-charts-react": "^9.0.1",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
```

Did the import change to a 'default', or what can I be doing wrong.  Seems pretty simple

Trying to use a standard import:
`import { AgChartsReact } from 'ag-charts-react';`

and I'm getting the error:
`export 'AgChartsReact' was not found in 'ag-charts-react'`

Comment: What's your project structure like? Are you using a bundler (e.g. webpack, rollup)?

Comment: Using Webpack, started with a template.  Older version of this: https://themeforest.net/item/easypro-developer-friendly-react-bootstrap-4-admin-template/21798550?gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAs6-sBhBmEiwA1Nl8s9IbbuiAYOezSlLMQ5NAYySJFLkgarhBfH5LMjwnztq_Wl-jNthoMxoCntIQAvD_BwE

Comment: As far as I can tell, ag-chart-react is now only released with typeScript, and no longer has .js files with it as of 9.0.0, so if I have that correct, I need to update webpack to support .ts files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, ag-charts-react versions 9.0.0 and 9.0.1 are not published with a umd/ (Universal Module Definition) as previous versions are.  That was the file needed for it to work with my config.  I will just run a older version and see if I can find out if that missing DIR was a mistake or forward approach to the ag-charts-react package.

Thanks G1N, that simple question helped me track it down.